# How can I write a join that does not fail if something is not found?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to determine on which page the user is on, using SEF URLs. It's working like this:

```
public function getIdsByPath(array $path, $langId) {
    $select = 'SELECT ';
    $from = ' FROM pages t0 ';
    $where = 'WHERE ';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($path); $i++) {
        $ii = $i - 1;
        if($i > 0) {
            $select .= ', ';
            $from .= "LEFT JOIN pages t$i ON (t$i.pid = t$ii.id) ";
            $where .= ' AND ';
        }
        $select .= "t$i.id";
        $where .= "t$i.alias = ?";
    }
    $where .= " AND t0.pid = ?";
    $q = $this->db->prepare($select.$from.$where);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($path); $i++) {
        $q->bindValue($i + 1, $path[$i]);
    }
    $q->bindValue($i + 1, $langId);
    $q->execute();
    return $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}
```

The purpose of this method is to go through a page hierarchy and verify if it is correct. The problem, however, is that since the hierarchy is presented as a SEF URL, like `path/to/page/module/action/123` at some point the items in the `explode('/')`'d aforementioned string do not represent pages anymore, but other variables.

If I feed this whole string `path/to/page/module/action/item/123` to the method, the query will find nothing, because of the `JOIN` statement. I tried every other `JOIN` I could think of too. All of them determine, that since ALL of the stuff wasn't found, NOTHING was found period.

This whole approach works nicely if other variables are first detected from the URL by keywords, but that results in more verbose URLs, which I do not want. `path/to/page/some-module/edit/123` would change into `path/to/page/module/some-module/action/edit/item/123`. Not nice.

Is there a way to `JOIN` stuff so that MySQL sort of joins what it can and disregards the rest? Instead of stating "I'm going to tell you IF this page hierarchy is valid" this method I described should state "I'm going to tell you TO WHICH POINT this page hierarchy is valid."

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that although you are using LEFT JOIN, since you are specifying a value for each table in the WHERE clause, you are forcing each table to have a record, which renders a result that would be the same as an INNER JOIN.

Therefore, change

```
$where .= "t$i.alias = ?";
```

to

```
$where .= "(t$i.alias = ? OR t$i.id IS NULL)";
```

That will allow you take advantage of the LEFT JOIN and 'skip' the tables that don't match, while still returning results for what is found.

Your SELECT will then return the `id`s for those pages that were found, and then null for the remaining values which do not correspond to a page.